# Four quadrants in CSS

Tags: css

With this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8kh5Lw9r/ I get, as expected, four quadrants.

[image: four quadrants in CSS]

**HTML**

```
<div id="one"><p>One</p></div>
<div id="two"><p>Two</p></div>
<div id="three"><p>Three</p></div>
<div id="four"><p>Four</p></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}

#one {
    height: 40%;
    width: 35%;
}
#two {
    height: 40%;
    width: 65%;
}
#three {
    height: 60%;
    width: 35%;
}
#four {
    height: 60%;
    width: 65%;
}
```

But:

1. Why do the four paragraphs bundle when the DIVs are fine?
2. Is there a way to avoid duplication, by specifying the 40/60 and 35/65 divisions in one place?

**Edit:**
*I'd very much appreciate it if you point out errors in my understanding of how CSS works. An answer is nice, but telling me where I was wrong is much more helpful.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `div`s actually aren't fine. Changing the size and color of the borders might make it more clear, like in the following example.

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
}
#one {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  height: 40%;
  width: 35%;
}
#two {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 40%;
  width: 65%;
}
#three {
  border: 2px dashed green;
  height: 60%;
  width: 35%;
}
#four {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 60%;
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"><p>One</p></div>
<div id="two"><p>Two</p></div>
<div id="three"><p>Three</p></div>
<div id="four"><p>Four</p></div>
```

What's happening is they are all starting at position (0,0), but because they are all different sizes it makes a grid. Your percentages add up to 100%, but because they all have the same starting point, they are not actually taking up 100%. The largest one is 65% by 65%, therefore the entire grid is only 65% by 65%.

You can fix this by either removing the fixed size, or by setting the x and y coordinates if you do want the position to be fixed.

By using classes for the varying widths and heights you can avoid using ids.

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top    { height: 40%; top:    0; }
.bottom { height: 60%; bottom: 0; }
.left   { width:  35%; left:   0; }
.right  { width:  65%; right:  0; }
```

```html
<div class="top left"><p>One</p></div>
<div class="top right"><p>Two</p></div>
<div class="bottom left"><p>Three</p></div>
<div class="bottom right"><p>Four</p></div>
```

The `box-sizing: border-box` isn't really necessary, it just lets you combine the border into the size of the `div`. Without it, you will see two borders where they intersect and the `div`s may go off the end of the page a bit.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Because you set `position: fixed;` for all four DIVs. This fixes them in the upper left corner (in your case) of the viewport/window. Just erase that.

2.) Yes, use classes instead of IDs. These you can apply to more than one element, like

```
.x {
  height: 40%;
  width: 65%;
}

<div class="x">...</div>
```

Comment: Hmm.. Your answer is raking positive votes, but it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/muekzjoq/

Comment: you still have `position: fixed`on all of them. What you are seeing are all these DIV on top of each other!

Comment: @Calaf - Yeah it doesn't work. See my answer, ignore the upvotes. If you simply remove `position: fixed` as suggested, you lose all of the proportions. That needs to be fixed.

Comment: Without the fixed position, the height will only be as large as the content, therefore not actually a grid

Comment: then you have to position them in relation to the left/right/upper/lower border of the viewport, for example using `left: 35%; top: 45%;'. PLus you have to give them *both* a width and a height, plus the surrounding element (for example `body`) also needs to have a fixed height. But it would be better to have a common surrounding element and then use `position: absolute`on the child DIVs. Also in this case you need all these mentioned parameters - won't work otherwise. Or use floats, but not with position fixed!

Comment: to the downvoters: read the question: I answered the question, point 1 and point 2 - there is no reason for downvotes.

Comment: @Johannes, I think the problem is the answer doesn't actually seem to work. It might help you and others to show a fully working example either using a code snippet or something like jsfiddle. If you're right, you can prove it. If you're wrong, you can correct it.

Comment: @redbmk it's not about working, it's about answering the two questions, which I did. The question was not "how do I make this work?", but asked for explanation of two details.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```css
 .wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

#one {
    height: 40%;
    width: 35%;
}
#two {
    height: 40%;
    width: 65%;
}
#three {
    height: 60%;
    width: 35%;
}
#four {
    height: 60%;
    width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one"><p>One</p></div>
  <div id="two"><p>Two</p></div>
  <div id="three"><p>Three</p></div>
  <div id="four"><p>Four</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay.. it works! I'm puzzled about the wrapper though. Is this wrapper necessary?

Comment: Yes, the child elements need a base point. Otherwise setting `width: 65%` will be 65% of the body element, so full page. If you want the sections to be set sizes, you need to have a wrapping element. Unless you set each of the child elements, as fixed pixel widths and heights.

Comment: fullpage is indeed what I'm after. One reason is that it's a starting point to make the code work reasonably well on both desktop and mobile with less effort.

Comment: @Calaf - In that case, see my edited answer for a full page solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve those problems:

```css
body {
  height: 300px;
}

div {
    border: 1px dashed red;
    float: left;
}

#one, #two {
    height: 40%;
    border-bottom: none
}

#three, #four {
  height: 20%;
}

#one, #three {
    width: 35%;
}

#two, #four {
  width: 30%;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"><p>One</p></div>
<div id="two"><p>Two</p></div>
<div id="three"><p>Three</p></div>
<div id="four"><p>Four</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this can work

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
div {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
#box{
  height: 60%;
    width: 65%;
}
#one {
    height: 40%;
    width: 35%;
}
#two {
    height: 40%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 30%;
}
#three {
    top:40%;
    height: 20%;
    width: 35%;
}
#four {
   top:40%;
   left: 35%;
    height: 20%;
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
<div id="one"><p>One</p></div>
<div id="two"><p>Two</p></div>
<div id="three"><p>Three</p></div>
<div id="four"><p>Four</p></div>
</div>
```